# Looking for best way to approach user profiles

Tags: users

I'm looking for the best way to approach user profiles, I'll tell you what I want to achieve and maybe someone can give me some advice - There are a few things I'd like to do but not sure where to start, so here I go...

First I'd like 2 different user types, personal and business. When registering the user chooses which type of account they want and fills out the relevant form (personal and business will have different fields available to them, for example a business account will display a vat number where as a personal will not)

Then when a user creates a node I'd like fields from their profile to be displayed on their node, for example their name, location, picture and a link to their profile to name a few. (I would like this so people can search content based on users location for example)

I think these are the 2 main functions I'd like to get out of user profiles - what would be the best way to tackle this? I have seen a couple of modules - 1 being Profiles2 but I'm looking for an all in one solution if possible because I seem to be having trouble using multi modules for different tasks regarding this unless someone has a good guide on how to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry to reply to my own post, but I have been looking more at Profiles2 and think this may be the best approach, I have created 2 'Rolls' "Personal" & "Business", Now I'm thinking I will create 2 'Profile' types, 1 for each, and a personal roll can only use personal profile fields and business roll for business profile. I think I can do this but its all in my head at the moment, but how could I go about giving the user which type of account they want on registration? (Without having 2 separate registration pages) I can see a way to create 1 page for each type of registration but is there a way that the user can check a radio button for which type of account they want during registration, they will then be displayed with the relevant profile and wont be able to see the other profile type - Do you know what I mean? So just to summarize the user clicks register -> they choose a username and password and then they check a box for which account type they want, (in my case business or personal) once they click submit they have to fill out the profile they chose after their account is activated. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Profile2 is probably the best approach there.

However, I don't think you'll be able to switch within a single registration form without custom coding.

To present alternative registration form pages for profile type, you can use the module:

[profile2_regpath](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, sorry for the 'opinion' based question, I know what I want in my mind but wasn't really sure what I was asking. I have a question now which should be an easy answer hopefully, How do I create a page with 2 picture links so the user can select which type of account to create? So the user clicks register -> then they are taken to the page with 2 pictures, 1 for personal and 1 for business, the user clicks which type of account they want, then they are taken to the correct registration form? Thanks